# Generating a dynamic Buy Now button

Tags: paypal

I am currently speccing out a custom auction plugin for WordPress.  One thing I would like to do for each item is to generate a dynamic Buy Now link that will redirect to a PayPal screen with the item name and final price.

From what I can see, the only way to generate one of these buttons is to go to the form that generates the buttons for you.  Is there a js file that I can use to generate these buttons from a Wordpress admin area?  If so, can someone please provide a link so that I can begin reading up on the documentation?

Thank you

Comment: @DIDos adding PHP to my search query brought me to a few duplicates, it looks like I can just go ahead and create a button using something similar to http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples of how to create a "pay now" button on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704768/php-basic-pay-now-button-for-paypal) (with simple HTML form). I would rather not use the "insecure" forms.

For including it in Wordpress you need to create a PHP Script (Plugin) that creates you the button, either with a [library](https://github.com/brandonwamboldt/paypal-tools) or "by hand".
The second thing I would recommend is to give PayPal an URL they should call after a payment status change (IPN). Some libraries (as the one above) can help you with that.

Comment: thanks for the links!  I'll dig through these and start playing around.